# How to automate adding spaces around an ampersand in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, automation

Suppose, we are writing a logical expression in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
$a\&b$
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Questions:

1. What should be the space size around the '&' symbol: `\,` or `\>` or `\;`?
2. How can I automate adding the correct spaces around `&`? So I won't need to type `\;&\;` every time.

Comment: since this question is about a specific symbol, i identified it in the title.

Comment: Do you know about `$a \wedge b$`?

Comment: @Sigur Yes, just wanted to know, how to put spaces around my own symbols.

Comment: @user4035, so I recommend you to read about `\mathrel` and `\mathpunct` also.

Comment: @Sigur Will do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `symbol` can be set as binary operator `\mathbin`.

The amount of the space is `\medmuskip` and the space can be set via `\>`.

Manually, `\&` can be put into `\mathbin`, then TeX sets the space automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$a\mathbin{\&}b$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Also, `\&` can be redefined to add `\mathbin` in math mode automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand*{\&}{%
  \relax
  \ifmmode
    \mathbin{\char`\&}%
  \else
    \char`\&\relax
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
$a \& b$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

There's no definition for `\&` as a math character, so it's regarded as a letter.

However, simply defining it as a math character would make it unusable in text mode, so a branching should be used:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\&}{%
  \ifmmode\expandafter\mathbin\fi\char`&
}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\&}{%
  \ifmmode\expandafter\mathbin\fi\char`&
}

\begin{document}

Duck \& Co.

$a \& b$

\end{document}
```

[image]